# how to add single parent element for all the child nodes in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this below code is working fine. But, on this, when click first element [Node 1], then, it is copied to target div but without parent 'UL'. The same is happening when i click the child node directly. I mean, if i click the Node 1.1, Node 1.2 etc, then, these should be captured inside single 'UL' element. i.e.,

this below should be changed to

```
`<li><span>Node 1.1</span></li><li><span>Node 1.2</span></li>`
```

(this is what i am getting right now)
as

```
<UL><li><span>Node 1.1</span></li><li><span>Node 1.2</span></li></UL>
```

the same should happen if select 'Node 1' also.

Any idea? Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/fjaLsnLh/7/     Kindly make your amendments on this fiddle link please.

Comment: Why not add a `ul` to the target div and then append, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/fjaLsnLh/9/

Comment: @ShaunakD, I followed your idea and made my code working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use jquery's [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```
$('li').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fjaLsnLh/12/

Comment: Hi, your info is ok, but, it is not working as expected, Could you please alter the code in 'jsfiddle' please?

Comment: In what way is it not working as expected? What do you expect it to do that it's bit doing?

Comment: Actually, I was making this condition when user click the each checkbox, whenever, user click the check box, it should add 'ul' to wrap all the 'li'. Where I supposed to paste the above code on the code snippet? I am confusing..

Comment: @madalinivascu, when you uncheck the box, it should remove all the lists back, but, as of now, your code is not working as expected. Could you please have a look on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery method wrapAll() to achieve this.

Syntax:

```
$(selector).wrapAll(wrappingElement);
$('li').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
```

eg:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("li").wrapAll("<ul></ul>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <UL>
    <li><span>Node 1.1</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>Node 1.2</span>
    </li>
  </UL>
  <button>Wrap a div element around all p elements</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Could you please make this work in JSfiddle link that i copied?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<li>s` to a `<ul>` directly instead of a `<div>`. No need for wrapping etc...

http://jsfiddle.net/fjaLsnLh/11/